# only one of the div is visible at a time in css

Tags: dojo

I am using twitter bootstrap to show my header and content but I am only able to see only header or the content at a time

here is my html code:

```
<div  data-dojo-type="pages/header/widget/mastheader"></div>

    <div  class="row" >

         <div class=" col-md-5" 
            data-dojo-type="pages/pathmaker/widget/pathMakerWidget"></div> 

         <div class=" col-md-7" 
            data-dojo-type="pages/SubscribersMap/widget/subscriberMapWidget"></div>

    </div>
```

In this particular html code,only header is visible, and if I use the below html then only the content is visible:

```
<div  class="row" >

     <div class=" col-md-5" 
        data-dojo-type="pages/pathmaker/widget/pathMakerWidget"></div> 

     <div class=" col-md-7" 
        data-dojo-type="pages/SubscribersMap/widget/subscriberMapWidget"></div>

</div>

<div  data-dojo-type="pages/header/widget/mastheader"></div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that this is more of a dojo question than a css question

Comment: I have no where manipulated css with dojo, it has more to do with twitter bootstratp and css

Comment: just and update subscriberMapWidget is using google maps